# Convergence of sum of exp. decaying pdf // When does L^2 convergence imply a.s. convergence?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

**The problem:**

Let $X_t^i$ $(i \in Z)$ be integer valued random variables on the same probability space.
Let $m: Z \rightarrow  R $ be a symmetric probability density on the integers which has exponential decay.

Assuming that we know  $lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} E[(X_t^0 - X_t^i)^2]/t = 0$  $ \forall i$, how can we proof that $lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i \in Z} \frac{m(i)}{t} E[{X_t^0}^2 - {X_t^i}^2] \rightarrow 0$ ?

**My thoughts so far:**

I am hoping to show that $E[(X_t^0 - X_t^i)^2]/t \rightarrow  0$ implies $E[X_t^2 - {X_t^i}^2]/t \rightarrow 0$. My idea is that, as $lim$ $\frac{X_t^0}{\sqrt{t}}$ $=$ $lim$ $\frac{ X_t^i}{\sqrt{t}}$ in $L^2$, the r.v.s should be the same in the limit and thus $\frac{E[X_t^2 - {X_t^i}^2]}{t} = 0$ in the limit.

However, $L^p$ convergence does not imply a.s. convergence. Is there any way around this?

As $m(i)$ decays so nicely, we may have integrability of each summand.

By convergence and integrability we can exchange the limit and the sum by Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem. The limit of each summand is 0, as shown above.

---

Any hint or guidance into the right direction is appreciated!